# Implementing back-forward in a Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm responsible for a Flex application which shows cards/tiles. A click on each card sends a request to the server and then the Flex app renders new cards from the data returned from the server.
Now I need to add a back-forward functionality, so that after several clicks on cards, I will be able to return to the previous requests. As I understand it, I just need to save some kind of a stack of URLs which were sent to the server.
The need is for regular back-forward, so that if I'm viewing card X, then click back and then click on a different tile, I can drop card X from my data structure and forget it.

What data structure would you recommend using? Any examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) and simply use the browser's back/forward functionality. Here's a [video tutorial](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=911) to get you started.